# Is it possible to add user picture column for task list based on AssignedTo field?

Tags: wss-3.0, image, caml-renderpattern

I'm searching for a way to have a task list view where AssignedTo column contains user profile image just as i can in User Info List.

By looking at hows its done in User Info List, i see a PictureDisp calculated column with custom DisplayPattern that renders the image. This is schema for the field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Field ID="{cd01f312-731b-4711-97f8-a18c37b1eeb5}" Type="Computed" ReadOnly="TRUE" Name="PictureDisp" DisplayName="Attēls" Sortable="FALSE" Filterable="FALSE" EnableLookup="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" AuthoringInfo="(attēls)" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="PictureDisp">
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="Picture" />
  </FieldRefs>
  <DisplayPattern>
    <HTML><![CDATA[<a ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="]]></HTML>
    <URL />
    <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
    <HTML><![CDATA[<IMG width="62" height="62" border="0" SRC="]]></HTML>
    <Switch>
      <Expr>
        <Column Name="Picture" />
      </Expr>
      <Case Value="">
        <HTML><![CDATA[/_layouts/images/person.gif" ALT="]]></HTML>
        <HTML HTMLEncode="TRUE">Attēla vietturis:</HTML>
        <HTML><![CDATA[ ]]></HTML>
        <Column Name="Title" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[ " > ]]></HTML>
      </Case>
      <Default>
        <Column Name="Picture" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[" ALT="]]></HTML>
        <HTML HTMLEncode="TRUE">Attēls:</HTML>
        <HTML><![CDATA[ ]]></HTML>
        <Column Name="Title" HTMLEncode="TRUE" />
        <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
      </Default>
    </Switch>
    <HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML>
  </DisplayPattern>
</Field>
```

So it uses the "Picture" column to get the value of user profile picture URL to render the image.

Obviously, for a task list i don't have a "Picture" column. Is there any way i can make for a task list a PictureDisp field with custom DisplayPattern and lookup that information from Site User Info List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a column of type *Person or Group*, you get the option to add the column *Name (with picture)*.

If you check the *fields* feature in the 14 hive, there is a property on the Field definition called *ShowField*:

```
<Field ID="{078B9DBA-EB8C-4ec5-BFDD-8D220A3FCC5D}" 
        FieldRef="Editor" 
        RowOrdinal="0" 
        ReadOnly="TRUE" 
        Type="User" 
        List="UserInfo" 
        Name="MyEditor" 
        SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
        DisplayName="$Resources:core,Modified_By;" 
        StaticName="MyEditor" 
        FromBaseType="TRUE" 
        Required="FALSE" 
        Group="" 
        ShowField="NameWithPicture" 
        AuthoringInfo="$Resources:core,picture_and_name;"/>
```

If you have a User type field with Showfield="NameWithPicture" you should get the users picture. Is this sufficient, or is it a problem that you get the name as well?

Comment: Thank you, i'll take a look at this. And having a name is no problem, i need that too. And anyway I suspect if you change ShowField to "PictureDisp" it will only show picture. By the way for WSS3 i have only a 12 hive :)

Comment: Thank you, this works. I actually modified existing AssignedTo field and set ShowField="NameWithPicture" to make it work. Thank you for solution. However if i choose to add a new field with similar schema and a FieldRef attribute, it won't show picture, but i can choose to show simple text fields like email, etc.